# I have written this code to remove strings using regex, can this be optimized?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

## Input

```
Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32
```

## Code

```
string = 'Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32 '

new_string = re.sub('^Office_Employee_','',string)

new_string_2 = re.sub('\_Temp32$','',new_string)

print new_string_2
```

## Output

```
19981128
```

Comment: consider extracting the needed number rather than removing side substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract the needed number using `re.search()` function:

```
string = 'Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32 '
matches = re.search(r'(?<=_)\d+(?=_)', string)
result = matches.group(0) if matches else ''

print result
```

The output:

```
19981128
```

**Edit:** pattern `_(\d+)_` can be used as an alternative

```
matches = re.search(r'_(\d+)_', 'Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32 ')
result = matches.group(1) if matches else ''
print result # will give same result as first approach
```

---

Execution time measurements:

```
python3 -m timeit -n 1000  -s  "import re;matches = re.search(r'(?<=_)\d+(?=_)', 'Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32 '); result = matches.group(0) if matches else ''"
1000 loops, best of 3: 0.0147 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -n 1000 -s  "import re;matches = re.search(r'_(\d+)_', 'Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32 '); result = matches.group(1) if matches else ''"
1000 loops, best of 3: 0.0148 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit -s  "import re;matches = re.search(r'(?<=_)\d+(?=_)', 'Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32 '); result = matches.group(0) if matches else ''"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00708 usec per loop
python3 -m timeit -s  "import re;matches = re.search(r'_(\d+)_', 'Office_Employee_19981128_Temp32 '); result = matches.group(1) if matches else ''"
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00717 usec per loop
```

Comment: This can be further improved as you don't actually need the look behind and look ahead: `r'_(\d+)_'` will do. Your regex needs 117 steps and my suggested one only needs 9.

Comment: @DeepSpace, show the details of such calculation *needs 117 steps*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'd guess it's these are the numbers regex101 gives when testing (as a pcre pattern). Note that lookbehinds/-aheads are expensive to evaluate, especially when starting a pattern - compared to simple matching.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Indeed, these are from regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ZT7XAV/1 Note that it takes 117 steps if using the global flag. Without it takes 41.